# Appending data to Datatable

Tags: c#

I am adding data to a dataset using the below code

```
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table11"
dr = cmdExcel.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable("WK11");
dtExcel.Load(dr);
ds.Tables.Add(dtExcel);
```

Now i want to add the content from Table2 to the same datatable WK11. Is it possible?

```
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table12"
dr = cmdExcel.ExecuteReader();
dtExcel.Append(.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the

```
dtExcel.ImportRow()
```

function which will append new row to the dtExcel Table.

Comment: but i should supply with Row but i have to dump the entire datareader

Comment: you can loop through rows and add them one by one.